# Chain of responsibility in RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to make a three tasks running successively based on the parameter. Originally, I implemented this idea with `asynctask` but trouble comes a lot. I would like to change the idea to `RxJava` but I have no idea how to implement it.

> Task A ( params: integer , response: String[] )
>
> Task B ( params: String[] , response: long)
>
> Task C ( params: long, response : boolean)
>
> Task A -> B -> C

Can anyone give me a simple example how to implement it ? Thank you.

I found this library useful but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void main() {
        Observable.just(yourFirstMethod(42))
                .map(strings -> yourSecondMethod(strings))
                .map(aLong -> yourThirdMethod(aLong))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(aBoolean -> { 
                    ...
                }, throwable -> {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                });
    }

    public String[] yourFirstMethod(int param) {
        ...
    }

    public long yourSecondMethod(String[] param) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean yourThirdMethod(long param) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: If you're using lambdas, you could use method references. E.g., `.map(this::yourSecondMethod).map(this::yourThirdMethod)`.

Comment: Sure, just omitted them for readability. From my experience method references are quite difficult for starters.

Comment: yourFirstMethod will not run on IO thread, it will run on whatever thread you are calling from, I would guess UI thread. Use defer() and then inside just(). I would also use .subscribeOn() right after just() ( I mean defer() ), and observeOn right before your UI thread code.