# For each in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

The RxJava worked at last week.From my Question, [Chain of responsibility in RxAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499485/chain-of-responsibility-in-rxandroid/35499774#35499774)

However, I would like to use foreach function in RxJava to loop  the result but it seems different. I cannot find method can be used or Might be I am in the wrong way???

> Task A ( params: integer , response: String[] )
>
> Task B ( params: String , response: long)
>
> Task A -> B

Can anyone know how to do so ? Thank you.

```
Observable.from(new Integer[] {1,2})
.map(new Func1<Integer, String[]>() {
    @Override
    public String[] call(String s) {
        return  new String[] { "One","Two","Three"};
    }
}).map(new Func1<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(String s) {
        return String.format("Testing:%s",s);
    }
});
```

I would like to do Sth like that

> Testing:One
>
> Testing:Two
>
> Testing:Three
>
> Testing:One
>
> Testing:Two
>
> Testing:Three

Comment: If you subscribe, you are doing a form of non-blocking for-each over the sequence of inputs.

Comment: I tried to use Observable.from(new Integer[]).map(integer -> String[]).subscribe(String) It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `flatMap`/`flatMapIterable` operators to perform the flattening of the second array:

```
Observable.range(1, 2)
.flatMapIterable(v -> Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three"))
.map(s -> String.format("Testing:%s", s))
.subscribe(System.out::println)
```